# Preference Module - When to Pass in Parent Dependencies

Tags: product, module, model, preference, construct

I am currently creating a preference module to add additional functionality to \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product and in reviewing some of the tutorials, example below, I noted that dependencies weren't being passed to the parent constructor.

Is this just a careless omission or do the dependencies only needed to be passed to the parent constructor in certain circumstances?

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\ProductPreference\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return "New Nameo";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use plugin as well to add additional functionality. refer https://github.com/pawan/module-sample-magento2/blob/main/module-catalog-sample/Plugin/ProductName.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dependencies and constructors are conditional if you're referring to preference/overriding class.

1. if you're using another dependencies which are not in parent class, you need to declare `__construct` and call parent `__construct`
2. if you're not using other dependencies, you can just skip to/DO NOT delare `__construct`, this will automatically call parent `__construct`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin

```
<?php

namespace Test\Catalog\Plugin;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return 'Test ' . $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are extending from your parent class, it get the all things.

If you want to use new classes then you can inject them in your child class.

For more details you can get best info from there :

[Magento 2 How to Override Model Class and pass the class in construct as dependency injection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320789/magento-2-how-to-override-model-class-and-pass-the-class-in-construct-as-depende)